# Export unique JSON values from two files

Tags: jq

I am trying to extract unique values between two JSON files. I see many jq posts on how to filter unique values within the same file, but not compare two.

Both of my files are in the same format:

```
{
"time":"2021-10-01T04:00:38.161Z",
"Number":2,
"signature":"e03756fa67a30d52837d3743d4d87e9a810c5e2ddf11061a976c386a742fa"
}
{
"time":"2021-10-01T04:01:38.164Z",
"Number":2,
"signature":"3b4d746ac2da2543047d8cc981db2464d4993065993449b321fc15d7f0aa6"
}
```

I would like to create a 3rd file which contains only unique values. If I must choose a single value to declare as unique, then I would select 'signature.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose a field that will be compared (e.g. `.signature`) and filter by that using `unique_by` in the comprehensive array obtained by using the option `--slurp` or `-s`:

```sh
jq -s 'unique_by(.signature)[]' file*.txt
```

Comment: @MonteCarloSims - You can use `unique_by` without having to choose a single field.  Indeed, from your question, it sounds like you really want `unique_by(.)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I totally understand what you are trying to explain to us here, but if you are trying to extract/export it from your file to a command or a retrieval command, then you would need to specify which files need to be included, along with where you want to post that text to.

With any files you can extract data. For example, if you were using Sqlite:

```
db.fetch(`data_specified_here`)
```

> **Note:** This would fetch the data from the database—or for you db file— then what you would want to do is either log or print out the data.

Since you have things like "time" and "Number"'s, you'd want to specify that that (meaning "time":**2021-10-01**, and so on) you need to specify that it is the string, or input you with to take out from your file.

If this didn't help, please re-ask your question with a little more detail and I can help more. I just gave a general rundown on how to fetch something from the DB, or in your case "JSON".

Comment: Another thing, you can not necessarily extract it from 2 files via one command code, you'll need to specify 2 settings/codes that allow you to get them from 2 files.

Comment: I was a bit confused with what you were saying, so attempted to clarify your meaning with an edit. Please review and make sure that my edits are consistent with your intent. Also, I was still confused by the wording of "or input you with to take out from your file"—can you reword that part?